# 【PowerShell】 Is there a perfect way that the error is not written to $Error?

Tags: powershell

Is there a way to not write to the error variable when I run `.'Non-existent path'`?

Even if ErrorActionPreference is set to Ignore, it will be written to `$Error`.

Comment: And the problem with this is...? If you're not interested in the contents of `$Error`, don't read it. If you need the contents of `$Error` for other operations, either save the value before or use `-ErrorVariable`.

Comment: "Ignore isn't a valid value for the $ErrorActionPreference variable." (see: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_preference_variables?view=powershell-7.1), In the link you can find `SilentlyContinue`, maybe that helps?

Comment: Alternatively remove the `$Error` entry immediately after: `try{ . $nonExistingPath }catch{ $Error.RemoveAt(0) }`

Comment: Why not use `Test-Path` before you try to reference a path that might not exist?